# Homotopy extension property of a pushout - converse statement

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X, Y$ are topological spaces, $A \subset X$ be any subset, $f: A \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous map. Let $Z$ denote a pushout of $f$, i.e. $Z = X \cup_f Y$ - adjunction space.

It is well-known that if $(X,A)$ has HEP for some space $W$, then so does $(Z,Y)$ for $W$.

What about the converse statement?

> Suppose $(Z,Y)$ has HEP for $W$. Then $(X,A)$ has HEP for
> $W$.

I am doing this as an exercise from E.Spanier "Algebraic Topology", Ex. B.4 from Chapter I.

But I don't know how to even start. Suppose we are given $G: A \times I \rightarrow W$ and $g: X \rightarrow W$ s.t. $G(x,0) = g(x),\forall x\in A$.
How can we get the maps $Y \times I \rightarrow W$ and $Z \rightarrow W$ to use the HEP of $(Z,Y)$?

I looked through many books, and I could find only the proof of the first general statement.
The converse one is mentioned in a book Basic Algebraic Topology by Shastri, but again as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out to be false.

Take $X$ and $A \subset X$ such that $(X,A)$ doesn't have HEP for $W$. Take $Y=\{*\}$.
Then pair $(Z,Y)$ is cofibration, because for any given $\{*\} \times I \rightarrow W$ we can obtain $Z \times I \rightarrow W$ just by mapping $Z$ to $\{*\}$. So it gives a counterexample.